# Automatically log facebook user into my site

Tags: php, facebook, single-sign-on

I've set up a facebook login for my site, using the faceboko php-sdk example.php method. It's working fine, but I want a user who has already allowed my site once to be automatically logged into my site, if they're logged in facebook.

Currently, if a user who has previously 'allowed' my application visits my site while logged in with facebook, they need to click `login with facebook`, then they are redirected and logged-in. Even though after that click, they don't need to provide any credentials or anything. Thus I would just like this step to be removed and for a user to be automatically logged in.

I hope that makes sense. Thanks

Comment: i'm pretty sure the js button distributed with the fb sdk already does this by default.

Comment: well... the js sdk button was giving me errors (and didn't do that), and i like being able to use php. I guess I could use both. But, I would like a php command for basically FB.getLoginStatus

Comment: wait for the new release of the Facebook Javascript SDK. It is [supposed](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/503/) to be today...

Answer (score -1):

This is discussed on their site.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

> Facebook Platform uses OAuth 2.0 for
>   authentication and authorization.
>   While you can add login to your site
>   using OAuth 2.0 directly (see our
>   Authentication Overview), the open
>   source JavaScript SDK is the simplest
>   way to use Facebook for login.
>
> [...]
>
> In order to log the user into your
>   site, three things need to happen.
>   First, Facebook needs to authenticate
>   the user. This ensures that the user
>   is who they say they are. Second,
>   Facebook needs to authenticate your
>   website. This ensures that the user is
>   giving their information to your site
>   and not someone else. Lastly, the user
>   must explicitly authorize your website
>   to access their information. This
>   ensures that the user knows exactly
>   what data they are disclosing to your
>   site.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

> By testing for the presence of the
>   session object within the response
>   object, you can be sure the user is
>   known to your application and you can
>   begin to make further calls to the
>   Facebook APIs. If the session object
>   is not present, the user is either not
>   logged into Facebook, or has not
>   authorized your application.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Check the client side flow section to see when you get the authentication token you need to be passing around.

> If the user is already logged in, we
>   validate the login cookie that we have
>   stored on the user's browser,
>   authenticating the user. If the user
>   is not logged in, they are prompted to
>   enter their credentials

Comment: It has a walk through of the entire process here. You need an app_id to be able to use it. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/#login

Comment: could you be more specific though, i tried $cookie = get_facebook_cookie(YOUR_APP_ID, YOUR_APP_SECRET) and that gave me an error unexpected T_STRING... my problem is pretty specific, i have a working auth system, I just want to detect if a user is logged in facebook and if they've allowed my site before to automattically log them in

Comment: I don't think you have access to the cookie like that. and i don't see any useful functions on their end regarding getting that cookie. The OAuth will redirect you around and they will be logged in per their documentation, ill quote it above.

Comment: can you explain how this answers my question, I've gotten the auth to work.. First facebook auths the user, then they auth my site, then they give me their info, then they explicitly ALLOW my site... but then they logg off, come back the next day.. they don't have to re ALLOW mysite, all they do is click a  login with facebook button, I can even just redirect them to the link's href and it loggs them in, i just want to know WHO i can redirect to automatically log them in (i.e. which user's are already allowed on my site).. this is what the FB.getLoginStatus() does I think, but I want php

Comment: in the js quote above that information is included. the flow that is shared in the authentication document is where the answer lies. Having it be PHP related i think you are going to be having some difficulty, but you can do a curl grab and get the response just as they show in the server side php example.